# Matrices with a negative entry on the diagonal are never valid

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A matrix $A$ is valid iff:

i) $A$ is symmetric.

ii) $A$ is positive semi-definite.

How do I show that if the matrix $M$ has a negative entry on the diagonal, then $M$ is not valid (in this case this means that it is not positive-semi-definite).

EDIT: Others might have different proofs but I am stupid, the solution is:

A matrix $M\in R^{nxn}$ is positive semi-definite iff for all $x\in R^n:xAx^T \geq0$. Let $m_{kk}$ be the negative entry on the diagonal and $e_k\in R^n$ be the the vector with only zeros except a 1 at the $k$th position. Then $e_kAe_k^T <0$.

Comment: What would $e_k^T Me_k$ be?

Comment: Yeees, thank you. This tought came exactly when I posted the question...

Comment: Your proof is good.